# Storing (partial) Proguard obfuscation mapping in code

Tags: android, gradle, reflection, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

In an android Java code like this:

```java
String methodName = "myMethod"

public void myMethod() {
}
```

Is it possible to figure out the obfuscated name of the method at runtime?
I know I can ask Proguard to not obfuscate that method, but I'm looking for a way to avoid that and still be able to use it through reflection.

I can't find a Proguard configuration for that, but I'm wondering if there could be a gradle task for merging the generated mapping?

Comment: Hey, Can you share your use case for this functionality?

Comment: What functionality? I have a string constant that holds the name of a method. After obfuscation, the method name doesn't match the string anymore. So I want to find a way to figure out the new name at runtime.

Comment: I would like to know why u need to store method names as String. So maybe we will be able to resolve your issue without paying with proguard

Comment: To be able to call those methods through reflection at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the method name from inside the method, you can use

```java
String methodName;

public void myMethod() {
    methodName = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
}
```

Or, in newer Java versions

```java
String methodName;

public void myMethod() {
    methodName = StackWalker.getInstance(Set.of(), 1)
        .walk(s -> s.map(StackWalker.StackFrame::getMethodName).findFirst())
        .orElseThrow();
}
```

When you need the name from the outside, i.e. with calling it, you can mark the method with an annotation and search for it.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @interface Marker {}

@Marker
public void myMethod() {
}
```

```java
String name = Arrays.stream(ContainingClass.class.getDeclaredMethods())
    .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(Marker.class))
    .map(Method::getName)
    .findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

As said by others, not to use Reflection might be the better option. E.g., referring to the method using a matching functional interface, is not a reflective access:

```java
Runnable method = this::myMethod;

public void myMethod() {
}
```

This will keep working after obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly in my case I'm dealing with many classes and methods, so I was trying to avoid adding an identifying annotation for each separately. But it seems that there isn't a automated way for that.

Answer (score 1):

Code obfuscation usually just renames classes and variables to short and random text, keeping proper dependencies at the same time. There is no way to get the obfuscated name of the function as it is generated randomly and always different per each run.

Here are some options:

1. Instead, exclude the class from obfuscation and name your function with random text if you want to keep it unreadable.

   -keep class <com.package.DontObfuscate>
2. After the first obfuscation, keep `mapping.txt` file and add a line to your `proguard-rules.pro`

   -applymapping mapping.txt

That's will keep from generating new names for classes/variables.

> `-applymapping` - Specifies to reuse the given name mapping that was printed out in a previous obfuscation run of ProGuard. Classes and class members that are listed in the mapping file receive the names specified along with them. Classes and class members that are not mentioned receive new names.

3. Look for a way to not use reflection in your code with class/interface extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I think the `applymapping` option would be the closest to what I want to do